# Count the number of times two values appear in a column based on the unique values of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the dataframe below:

```
year<-c("2000","2000","2001","2002","2000")
gender<-c("M","F","M","F","M")
YG<-data.frame(year,gender)
```

In this dataframe I want to count the number of "M" and "F" for every year and then create a new dataframe like :

```
year M F
1 2000 2 1
2 2001 1 0
3 2002 0 1
```

I tried something like:

```
library(dplyr)
ns<-YG %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  count(YG$gender == "M")
```

Comment: Maybe `table(YG)` ?

Comment: Avoid using `$` within pipes `count(gender == "M")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `count` and `spread` to get the df format and use `fill = 0` in `spread` to fill in the 0s:

```
library(tidyverse)
YG %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  count(gender) %>%
  spread(gender, n, fill = 0)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   year [3]
  year      F     M
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2000      1     2
2 2001      0     1
3 2002      1     0
```

Comment: No need for last mutate_all, just use `fill = 0` inside spread.

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks! I always forget about this option.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `reshape2`:

```
dcast(YG, year~gender)

  year F M
1 2000 1 2
2 2001 0 1
3 2002 1 0
```

Or a different `tidyverse` solution:

```
YG %>%
 group_by(year) %>%
 summarise(M = length(gender[gender == "M"]),
           F = length(gender[gender == "F"]))

  year      M     F
  <fct> <int> <int>
1 2000      2     1
2 2001      1     0
3 2002      0     1
```

Or as proposed by @zx8754:

```
YG %>%
 group_by(year) %>%
 summarise(M = sum(gender == "M"),
           F = sum(gender == "F"))
```

Comment: Maybe just M = sum(gender == “M”) ?

Comment: @zx8754 that is indeed very straightforward, added it to my post. Thanks.